# Dependant country state filter on magento 2 data grid using UI component

Tags: magento2

Corresponding states to be shown on state filter while selecting a county.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code tested till 2.3.5

```
<field name="country_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
        </item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
    </argument>
</field>

<field name="region_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
    </argument>
</field>
```